# Struts2 how switch locale on login?

Tags: struts2, internationalization, locale

I have an action viewLoginAction that will redirect to login.jsp.  In my action I want to set the locale for the session.  I will choose the Locale depends on the hostname.

http://patate  -> LOCALE.FRENCH
http://potato  -> LOCALE.ENGLISH

I try that in my action

```
if(french){
    ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(LOCALE.FRENCH);
} else {
    ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(LOCALE.ENGLISH);
}
```

but in my JSP.  The locale is always the server locale (French)

I obtain : "Prenom"  instead of "Firstname" when the locale is set to English in the action.

What I missed ?

EDIT

I found my problem.

```
// on set la locale maintenant if(clinique.getLangue().equals(Langue.ENGLISH)){ ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); } else { ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(Locale.FRENCH); }
```

works fine.. You just need to have a file global_en.properties and global_fr.properties.

I tough it worked like Struts 1 and use the default global.properties, but look like it doesn't work like that.

Answer (score 0):

What i assume is that in your case 
`ActionContext.getCurrent().setLocale().` Unfortunately, it seems that a fresh new ActionContext is created when the action is invoked, and the locale is reset to the default.

Here is a similar thread for the same and i also believe that you need to achieve this by using a custom interceptor

[SO Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292981/how-to-set-locale-in-a-custom-struts-2-actionmapper)

Hope this will help you

Comment: I try that, but got the same problem.

Comment: I found my problem.

// on set la locale maintenant if(clinique.getLangue().equals(Langue.ENGLISH)){ ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(Locale.ENGLISH); } else { ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(Locale.FRENCH); }

works fine.. You just need to have a file global_en.properties and global_fr.properties.

I tough it worked like Struts 1 and use the default global.properties, but look like it doesn't work like that.