# Struts2 change locale

Tags: session, struts2, request, locale

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the locale into an action, and not by an url parameter...

In fact I have an authentication action, and regarding the user which was authenticated I want to switch to an appropriated locale.

I tried :

```
session.put("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE", "my_locale")
```

or

```
session.put("WW_TRANS_I18N_LOCALE", new Locale("my_locale"))
```

but still nothing...

any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

you should pass your locale information as parameter to the action. something like this:

```
<s:url id="url" action="your-action" >
   <s:param name="request_locale" >${your-locale}(e.g. de, en, etc.)</s:param>
</s:url>
```

**UPDATE 1**

here is the link, that may helps you. [How to set locale in a custom Struts 2 ActionMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1292981/how-to-set-locale-in-a-custom-struts-2-actionmapper)

You can also try this out, but i'm not sure, if it works. Put this snippet to your action class.
    ActionContext.getContext().setLocale(new Locale("your-locale"));

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use:
`ServletActionContext.getContext().setLocale(new Locale("en","US"));`